# EIDE to SATA converter fails to show the Hard Drive in the OS

Tags: hard-drive, conversion, sata

I recently bought a new PC based on Asus Crosshair IV Formula and AMD 965 Phenom II x4.

After connecting my new SATA hard drive (working perfect) I wanted to connect my old PATA drive with an EIDE to SATA converter (MANHATTAN IDE to SATA 150 Converter).

However it does not seem to be recognised by the system. How can I fix this?

Comment: obvious question: are all data and power cables securely connected?

Comment: What type of converter, add in card or one of those piggyback models that plugs into the back of the drive? piggyback type are prone to this type of problem, most are total junk.

Answer (score 0):

I would be doubting the converter. Grab a cheap sata/ide-to-usb converter off of ebay.. with shipping and little psu ~10$.

And just in case this doesnt fix it, these things are awesome and always come in handy.

ohh and its an awesome deal!

http://cgi.ebay.com/USB-2-0-IDE-SATA-S-ATA-2-5-3-5-HD-HDD-Adapter-Cable-/180550148600?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item2a09a0a1f8#ht_4020wt_1141